# Yii Framework - Storing field from a different table into a model

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I need some help with the Yii 2.x framework.

I have 2 tables, `stuff` and `table`, each with their own models, `Stuff` and `Table`.

`stuff` and `table` share a key. `stuff` contains `table_id` which links to `id` in `table`.

The `stuff` controller contains the following code to retrieve all fields from `stuff` and the `age` field from `table`:

```
$model = Stuff::find ()
                ->select (['`stuff`.*', '`table`.`age`'])
                ->leftJoin ('table', '`stuff`.`table_id`=`table`.`id`', [])
                ->where (['table_id' => $id])
                ->one ()
```

Once executed, `$model` contains everything from the `stuff` table, but does not contain the `age` field, even though the generated SQL does retrieve it. I have found that adding `public $age;` into the `Stuff` model does store the `age` field, however this seems like a hack and feels dirty.

So my question is, is it possible to get the `$model` variable to store fields from a referenced table without altering the original model? If that's not possible, is there a more correct way of doing things than what I have already done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define relation in the stuff model like this

```
public function getTable()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Table::className(), ['id' => 'table_id']);
}
```

and then you can access it via referenced object like

```
$model->table->age
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access related model fields in the object oriented fashion, something like this:

```
$model->table->age
```

In the above expression, `table` is relation name in the `Stuff` model.

Comment: Your code works, hamed, however as Mohan pointed out above, you need the function getTable () defined first.